# Passing date picked from date picker to another Activity?

Tags: android, date, picker

I've had issues sending the date to another activity. For some reason the new Intent doesn't accept `Datepicker.this` and gives me a this is not an enclosing class error. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: original Problem has been fix but now when i try to pass the date the app crashes.

```
public class Setup  extends Activity {       

private Button btnReport;
private AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
private String strWeekNumber = "strWeekNumber";
private Button openAppButton;
private TextView report_date;

int year_x, month_x, day_x;
static final int DIALOG_ID = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);



    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    year_x = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month_x = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day_x = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    setupOpenAppButton();
    showDialogOnButtonClick();

}

public void showDialogOnButtonClick() {


    btnReport = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReport);

    btnReport.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
                }
            }
    );


}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if (id == DIALOG_ID)
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, dpickerListner, year_x, month_x, day_x);
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpickerListner
        = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        year_x = year;
        month_x = monthOfYear + 1;
        day_x = dayOfMonth;


        Intent o = new Intent(Setup.this, UnitsForm.class);


        o.putExtra("Date", year_x +"/"+month_x + "/"+ day_x + "/");

        startActivity(o);



    }
```

};

UnitsForm Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    Bundle dateData = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (dateData == null) {
        return;
    }
    String dateSet = dateData.getString("Date");
    final TextView reportDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.report_date);
    reportDate.setText(dateSet);
```

Comment: Instead of Intent o = new Intent(DatePicker.this, UnitsForm.class); try this Intent o = new Intent(YourCurrentActivityName.this, UnitsForm.class);

Comment: if it worked, like answer

Comment: @Zylo Did you find solution for your edit in question??

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, the second activity is opening now but still isn't showing the date from the intent. Any thoughts ?

Comment: @Zylo Just check your value of dateset by putting a Log.i("Dateset",dateSet);

Comment: are you getting any error in logcat??

Comment: No error in the logcat, so I recon the date isn't getting passed properly and equals null. What do u think ?

Comment: You need to check that. Put that log statement after String dateset and check your logcat for its value.

Comment: It's all good I fixed it, I was wondering why I hadn't declared the layout, but it was duplicated in another part of the code therefore resetting the layout. Thanks for your help Man.

Comment: Great!!! and happy to help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass in Intent your actual context, in your case it will be

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Setup.this, UnitsForm.class);
```

instead of

```
Intent o = new Intent(DatePicker.this, UnitsForm.class);
```

The problem with your `UnitsForm` activity is that you need call `setContentView(R.layout.layout_for_UnitsForm);` before `final TextView reportDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.report_date);` Otherwise your `TextView` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
Intent o = new Intent(Setup.this, UnitsForm.class);
o.putExtra("Date", year_x +"/"+month_x + "/"+ day_x + "/");
startActivity(o);
```